# How to remove loop inside loop for this case

Tags: trigger, loop, cpulimit

I am doing trigger to fetch date conversion rate based on Opportunity Close Date and update opportunity field. The logic as below, as you notice I have to do loop inside loop in order to generate map for easy match with opportunity. Is there any other way I achieve this without doing loop inside loop?My concern , this might be cost cpu performance.

```
   public void updateCurrency (List<Opportunity> newOppList){
      // loop to generate the query
      for(Opportunity opp: newOppList){
            if(counter ==1){
              queryDatedRate+='(';
            }
            queryDatedRate+=' (StartDate <='+String.valueOf(opp.CloseDate) +' AND  NextStartDate >'+ String.valueOf(opp.CloseDate)+' ) ' ;

            if(counter==newOppList.size()){
                 queryDatedRate+= ' ) ';
            }
            else {
               queryDatedRate+=' OR ';

            }

            setISOCode.add(opp.CurrencyIsoCode);
            setCloseDate.add(opp.CloseDate);
            setCloseDateYear.add(opp.CloseDate.year());
            counter++;

        }
        if(setISOCode.size()>0){

           queryDatedRate+=' AND IsoCode IN :setISOCode';

        }



    List<DatedConversionRate> lstDatedExchange=Database.query(queryDatedRate);

   if( lstDatedExchange.size()>0){
         // loop to generate map
         for(Date dt :setCloseDate){

              for(DatedConversionRate dcr : lstDatedExchange){
                     if(dcr.StartDate<=dt && dcr.NextStartDate > dt){
                      system.debug('@@@mapDatedExchange gotData');
                      mapDatedExchange.put(dcr.IsoCode+'|'+String.valueOf(dt),dcr.ConversionRate); // this map is useful to match opportunity currency and close date

                  }
              }
         }
    }

    //so i can map it here
        for(Opportunity opp: newOppList){
        if(mapDatedExchange.containsKey(opp.CurrencyIsoCode+'|'+String.valueOf(opp.CloseDate))){
               opp.Dated_Exchange_Rate__c   =mapDatedExchange.get(opp.CurrencyIsoCode+'|'+String.valueOf(opp.CloseDate));

        }

    }// end of method
```

Comment: why this  if(dcr.StartDate<=dt && dcr.NextStartDate > dt) condition is required when you put the check in query. ?

Comment: @blackPerlSAF I expect it's because the opps being processed may all have different CloseDates so many different conversion rates could be returned, but not all of them are going to be valid for every opportunity. The query isn't quite what I would do though - I would simply loop over the opps and find the earliest and latest close dates and query for that range. Having multiple OR statements is overly complex and unnecessary. As far as the original question goes, I honestly think the two for loops are fine - especially if this is just done in a trigger context with 200 opportunities.

Comment: Yea exactly @robertwatson its not necessarily to check twice, that query will be too long. And using a earlier and latest close date is a good thought.

Comment: I loop because I want create map that has closedate as key to map with Opportunity. Because DateConversionRate only have field startDate and nextStartDate and it retrieve in the list.Please let me know how i compare directly.